# Why was Jacob still hanging onto the bucket?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Newt and Jacob travel to Paris by Portkey in *The Crimes of Grindelwald*. The Portkey in question is a bucket.

Yet, some time after they've arrived in Paris and gone to Place Cachée, he's still hanging onto the bucket.

[image: Jacob holding bucket]

The bucket wasn't exactly a precious or sentimental item for Jacob. So why didn't he just ditch it after he'd got to Paris rather than pointlessly carrying it round with him?

Comment: He was probably so distracted that he forgot about it. Also it makes him endearingly stupid to have him walking round Paris with a ridiculous object.

Comment: Jacob is, after all, a Muggle, er, No-Maj -- how would he know they don't need the bucket to get back to New York?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jacob appears to be in quite a daze after using the Portkey and is probably feeling somewhat unwell. I haven't watched the film in a while so can't remember if it's shown there, it probably is, but the screenplay also hints at he's thrown up into the bucket. If that's the case then keeping it around to re-use at a later date seems sensible.

> **SCENE 48**
>   **EXT. PLACE CACHÉE—DAY**
>
> **Jacob**: I didn’t like that Portkey, Newt.
>
> **Newt:** *(absently)* So you keep saying. Follow me.
>
> [...]
>
> **Newt:** Come on. That’ll wear off in a few minutes.
>
> <sub>*Fantasitc Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Later on when Newt tells Jacob to follow the feather he still seems to be in some sort of a daze and even offers the bucket out to Newt. This could indicate that he thought they could use the bucket again to do that and so he might have kept hold of it because he thought it would come in useful again.

> **SCENE 48**
>   **EXT. PLACE CACHÉE—DAY**
>
> [...]
>
> **Newt:**  Follow that feather.
>
> **Jacob**:  What?
>
> **Newt:**  Jacob, follow the feather.
>
> **Jacob**:  Follow the feather.
>
> **Newt:** *(of the Niffler)* Where is he? Ah, Accio Niffler.
>
> *The Niffler is carried by the spell back into the case. NEWT takes the case and dashes off.*
>
> *JACOB gestures toward the bucket in his hand.*
>
> **Newt:** Let go of the bucket!
>
> *JACOB drops the bucket and chases after NEWT.*
>
> <sub>*Fantasitc Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Comment: Nice.  I'd forgotten he tossed his cookies after the portkey trip...